# WP-CLI can't list posts

Tags: multisite, wp-cli

I have a WordPress Multisite (behind a firewall). I use WP-CLI for lots of things. But for some reason `wp post list` does not work. `wp post get` works. But `wp post list` always yields the same output, like this:

[image: screenshot of post list output]

As you can see, it's a table with no data. Does anyone have tips for debugging this issue?

As requested, I reformatted the command (made no difference) and added --debug.  There is a lot of output!

[image]

Added `post_type=page`:
[image]

Comment: I'd always put the `--url` option at the end. `wp post list --url=https://example.com/foobar`. Next add the `--debug` option. Can you please edit your question and post the debug output as well?

Comment: I didn't know about --debug. I'd paste the output, but it's 6000 characters too long. I can make a screenshot I guess.

Comment: Thank you! Everything looks good so far. What does `wp post list --post_type=page` return? And your site is among `wp site list`, yes?

Comment: Its about the same if I add the `--post_type=page` parameter. 

Yes, wp site list returns all sites, and /home-therapies/ is on the list.

Comment: That's really odd. And `wp post get` is really working?

Comment: yes, `wp post get` works. So weird.

Answer (score 1):

(I'll post here @photocurio's answer, as it's hidden in the comments)

```
wp post list --post_type=page      # will show only post-type=page
wp post list                       # will show only post-type=post
```

It's counter-intuitive command is also mis-documented, (which I hope to change), because:

1. pages **are** posts.
2. There's no "wp **page** list" command.
3. The docs don't mention that the list is **filtered by default**

I'd naturally expect that a query will be *inclusive* by default, so I was surprised not to find a page list in wp-cli's docs.